# Infinite (endless) paper in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, artboard

Can I create a document in Illustrator without attaching to the notion of paper with finite size?

Can you **DELETE the ARTBOARD?**

I reduced the artboard to some small size and remainder drawings persist. Can I delete the artboard at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to have some sort of an artboard.

Illustrator places artboards on a canvas space, which is sized at 16383 x 16383pt. You could create a new document with those dimensions.

Or, you can go to `View` > `Hide Artboards` (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) to just ignore whatever artboard you have defined.

Either way, be careful when exporting!